# Python 3 unittest doesn't load test suite

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing

I am trying to run tests after loading a test suite from a module and it doesn't seem to start any of test cases. I get this result:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

This is my project tree:

```
├── Tests
│   ├── NetworkTests
│   │   ├── AuthenticationTests.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── test_runner.py
```

`test_runner.py`:

```
from unittest.loader import TestLoader
from unittest.runner import TextTestRunner
from unittest.suite import TestSuite

from Tests import NetworkTests


loader = TestLoader()
suite = TestSuite((
    loader.loadTestsFromModule(NetworkTests)
    ))

runner = TextTestRunner()
runner.run(suite)
```

`NetworkTests/AuthenticationTests.py:`

```
import unittest

from common.testing_utils import NetworkingTestMixin


class AuthenticationTestCase(NetworkingTestMixin, unittest.TestCase):
    def test_authentication_success(self):
        pass

    def test_authentication_fail(self):
        pass
```

I call `python3 Tests/test_runner.py` command to run these tests. When I inspect this with debugger the suite is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've played around with `unittest` I don't have slightest idea why it works, however, this is what solved the problem (I've tried previously something similar but to no avail):

```
import unittest

# Leave this as it is. Otherwise tests will fail
from NetworkTests import *

unittest.main()
```

It displays an error message that it can't find NetworkTests, but it does somehow.